# Custom function in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have my servlet set up with thymeleaf templates, but I have no idea how to create a custom function or something similar in thymeleaf.

I basically want something like this:

```
<img th:src="${createJpegUrl(640,1,0.7,'some-key')}" />
```

That renders to:

```
<img src="/640/1/0.7/some-key.jpg"/>
```

I have been googling around and looking at the documentation without getting much closer.

Comment: what does createJpaUrl do? what would be wrong with th:src="@{'/640/1/0.7/some-key.jpg'}"

Comment: It would create the url based on the parameters. The url pattern might change, but I want the API to be consistent

Comment: I don't know of anything already out there. You are going to need to look at extending the existing. Take a look at this guide. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Extending-Thymeleaf.html

Comment: You could define the url-pattern in a message-source. Then it's constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending AbstractAttrProcessor will let you match a specific attribute.

I ended up extending AbstractElementProcessor and adding it to the StandardDialect. This was because I needed to do some additional stuff.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a helper class:

```
public class JpegHelper {
    public static JpegHelper getInstance() {...}
    public String createJpegUrl( int w, int h, double d, String key {
        ...
    }
}
```

then add it to the model in your controller:

```
 modelAndView.getModelMap().addAttribute( "jpegHelper", JpegHelper.getInstance() );
```

and use it in your thymeleaf template:

```
<img th:src="${jpegHelper.createJpegUrl(640,1,0.7,'some-key')}" />
```

If you want the helper to be available to all templates without adding it to the model, then register it in your spring configuration:

```
@Bean
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver( @Autowired SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine ) {
    ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine( templateEngine );
    thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
    thymeleafViewResolver.addStaticVariable( "jpegHelper", JpegHelper.getInstance() );
    return thymeleafViewResolver;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may also create and use a bean. I don't clearly understand the purpose of `createJpegUrl`, thus in the following example I implement a similar logic. Please, focus on the architecture of the solution, not in the implementation.

```
@Bean("pathGenerator")
public Function<String, String> pathGenerator() {
    return i -> "/" + String.join("/", i.split("|"));
}
```

You may add the aforementioned declaration in a `@Configuration` class in order the Bean to be available in your context (depending the DI mechanish you use).
Finally, use this Bean in your thymeleaf template like below,

```
<img th:src="${@pathGenerator.apply('640|1|0.7|' + some_key)}" />
```

Working with a functional interface, you may create a model to use as the input of the `Function` instead of a String which I used in the example.
Moreover, you may create your own `@FunctionalInterface` that will allow more than one input arguments, like the following example (**not tested**),

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface CreateJpegUrl<Integer, Integer, Double, String, String> {
    public String apply(Integer width, Integer height, Double ratio, String name);
}
```

and create a Bean like,

```
@Bean("pathGenerator")
public CreateJpegUrl<Integer, Integer, Double, String, String> pathGenerator() {
    return (w, h, r, n) -> {
        // Your logic
    };
}
```

Finally, use it like

```
<img th:src="${@pathGenerator.apply(640, 1, 0.7, some_key)}" />
```